Non-empty intersections in algebraic varieties
Is there a characterization of those irreducible algebraic varieties $X$ such that for every pair of irreducible sub-varieties $V,W \subseteq X$ the intersection $V \cap W$ is non-empty whenever $\dim(V) + \dim(W) \geq \dim(X)$?
It is well known that this holds for $X = \mathbb{P}^n$, because the affine cones above $V$ and $W$ intersect at the origin of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, and therefore also at some other point precisely because $\dim(V) + \dim(W) \geq \dim(X)$. Furthermore, this clearly holds if $\dim(X) \leq 1$.
I also believe that if $\dim(X) \geq 2$ then necessary conditions for the aforementioned property to hold are:

that $X$ should be projective, or at least proper. Surely, if $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is affine and $\dim(X) \geq 2$ then we can take $V$ and $W$ to be intersections of $X$ with parallel hyperplanes, and then $V \cap W = \emptyset$ even if $\dim(V) + \dim(W) \geq \dim(X)$.
that there should not exist an isomorphism between $X$ and a product $Y \times Z$ with $\dim(Y) \geq 1$ and $2 \dim(Z) \geq \dim(X)$. Indeed, in this case we can clearly take $V = \{P\} \times Z$ and $W = \{Q\} \times Z$ for two points $P \neq Q$ lying on $Y$.
similarly, I believe that there should not be a finite map between $X$ and such a product $Y \times Z$ with $\dim(Y) \geq 1$ and $2 \dim(Z) \geq \dim(X)$.

Do you know of other necessary or sufficient conditions? Does this property hold for example when $X$ is a simple abelian variety? The only thing I can say is that I believe that this property does not hold if $X$ is not simple, thanks to the general remarks above.

One small comment is that the condition in your second bullet point can be weakened: there should not be any morphism from $X$ onto a variety $Y$ with $1 \leq \operatorname{dim} Y \leq \frac12 \operatorname{dim} X$.

A trivial sufficient condition for smooth projective surfaces is that the Picard group is $\mathbb{Z}$.
